# Auto populate PowerPoint Slides

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am working on a project where I’m creating personalized order summary PowerPoint presentations for each location based on the items they ordered. I have to manually make about 150 presentations where the only thing that changes is the quantity field on each slide.

I have an excel report that I’m drawing all the data from. Is there a macro or some way to auto populate the quantity field on each slide so that I don’t have to manually enter it all?

Thanks!!

Comment: You could certainly create such a macro to automate the process.

Comment: This could be done very easily using a dummy file with 1 placeholder value for the quantity field - however, please show us what you've tried on your own first.

Comment: @dwirony how would I send it to you? I haven’t tried the automation myself but I could send the PowerPoint I made/ excel report I’m using with dummy data..

Comment: @Cocokrisp I don't do freelance work - if you're looking to hire a programmer, I'd recommend googling "Hire a VBA developer". Otherwise, if just post a screenshot of the powerpoint slide, your Excel sheet, and any code you've attempted so far.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! Posted a screen shot of a slide- the highlighted part is the variable field.  Again, haven’t tried any code yet. Was looking for any tips on if is this actually possible to automate and what to google for instructions on how to do it (like is it a macro or what is this function called?) super bad at this stuff sorry.....